# Some confusion of Go `net/http` under high concurrency

Tags: go, logging, go-gin

Some confusion under high concurrency.

I use [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) to test Gin, there's someting uncertainty. Gin seems doesn't concurrency safe.

```
  package main

  import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
  )

  var count int64 = 0

  func Test(c *gin.Context) {
    atomic.AddInt64(&count, 1)
    fmt.Println(count)
    c.String(200, "success")
  }

  func main() {
    gin.SetMode(gin.DebugMode)
    router := gin.New()
    router.GET("test", Test)
    router.Run(":8080")
  }
```

Test shell code

```
  wrk -t50 -c50 -d 1s http://localhost:8080/test
```

Gin output duplicate data

[image: duplicate data]

========update========

even if the print code like this.

```
  countCopy := count
  go func() {
    fmt.Println(countCopy)
  }()
```

I also use [ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) test it, the same problem.

========update========

The same with net/http, still has duplicate data.

```
  package main

  import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync/atomic"
  )

  var count int64 = 0

  func Test(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    atomic.AddInt64(&count, 1)
    fmt.Println(count)
    w.Write([]byte("success"))
  }

  func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/test", Test)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

  }
```

[image: data]

I try to use log package, which is safe from concurrent goroutines . The same.

```
log.Println(countCopy)
```

[image]

Comment: duplicate question at [github](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1351)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the returned value from `atomic.AddInt64(&count, 1)`, as `count` can change before you have a chance to print it:

```
func Test(c *gin.Context) {
    current := atomic.AddInt64(&count, 1)
    fmt.Println(current)
    c.String(200, "success")
}
```